# MVC for Wizard-Like Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a WebForms application with around 150 wizard kinds of logic and each wizard can have 3 to 7 steps. In my webforms app, I have a single aspx for each wizard and the logic is done using a multiview. I want to port the idea to a MVC application and I only know two ways to do it:

1. Using a single view foreach step and using a `RedirectToAction` methodology;
2. Using a single view with hidden divs and lots of javascript logic;

The first option will be very hard to maintain. If I have 150 wizards with 3 steps, I'll have at least 450 views. The second option will be javascript dependent with ajax logic;

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Are the aims of each wizard similar?  My temptation would be to define the *aims* of the wizards in code in a generic manner and define each wizard in another form (XML?).  Then pass the configuration to each wizard to a single action/view.

It won't be a simple implementation by any means, but would be easier to support going forward .

As for the javascript side, have a look at javascript framework (like ExtJS as suggested, or JQuery UI).

If it helps, I did a small mock-up of how one could implement a Wizard with jQuery as part of Fluqi - see http://fluqi.apphb.com/Demo/Wizard

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExtJS framework by sencha to achieve rich UI like Wizards without post back. and maintenance is also easy